# Django Query Many relation "includes"

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email_list = models.ForeignKey(EmailList, related_name='contacts')
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')

class EmailList(models.Model):
    customers = models.ManyToManyField('Customer',
        related_name='lists',
        through='Contact')

class Customer(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Now I want to query all customers that belong to a certain set of EmailLists by the EmailList id. I thought I was gonna be able to query this with something:

```
all_customers.filter(lists__id__contains=[email_list_1.pk, email_list_2.pk])
```

that is weird looking I accept and returns an empty Queryset, but what surprised is that it works when querying for only 1 EmailList like:

```
all_customers.filter(lists__id__contains=email_list_1.pk)
```

So my next step was to query with and AND operator:

```
customers.filter(Q(lists__id__contains=el1.pk) & Q(lists__id__contains=el2.pk))
```

but that returns and empty QuerySet. I would like to find a way to be able to query `lists__id__contains` passing an iterable of ids, or at least find a way to concatenate subqueries

Comment: `__contains` works for texts, you need to use `__in`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this fails is because the [**`__contains`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) works for text, and if the right operand is not a string, it will convert it to a string. So you basically query for something that has as substring `'[1, 4]'` (with `1` and `4` ids, these can be different).

## The customer is in *any* of the lists

You need to use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) here:

```
all_customers.filter(lists__id__in=[email_list_1.pk, email_list_2.pk])
```

or you can use a "logical or":

```
customers.filter(Q(lists__id=el1.pk) | Q(lists__id=el2.pk))
```

## The customer is in *all* of the lists

We can furthermore query for customers that are in all the lists by annotating and filtering:

```
ids = [email_list_1.pk, email_list_2.pk]

all_customers.filter(lists__id__in=ids).annotate(
    nlists=Count('lists')
).filter(
    nlists=len(set(ids))
)
```